# ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections

Tags: solana-program, deploy

I am trying to deploy an anchor program using `solana program deploy dummy_program.so`,

But I am getting the following error

```
Error: ELF error: ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections
```

Here is my env

```
- Linux, Pop OS
- anchor-cli 0.28.0
- solana-cli 1.14.20 (src:277b4c32; feat:1879391783)
- solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.14.20
- sbf-tools v1.29
- solana cluster version 1.16.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking through this [github issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/21067) and turns out I was missing the `#[program]` attribute and rust analyzer wasn't picking this up.